# Disable HTML5 video full screen mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I want to disable HTML5 video full screen control using CSS or Javascript. I have tried CSS and this is only working on Chrome.

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
}
```

How can I disable it in all the browers like Safari, IE and Firefox?

Thanks

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/

Comment: or is there any method to detect the FullScreen mode which works for all the browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should hide the native control. And use css create interface player for you with this you can customize anything you want.
I suggest you can use http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: is there any method to detect the FullScreen mode which works for all the browsers. –

Comment: Detect Fullscreen video player or browser fullscreen?

Comment: fullscreen video player

Comment: var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement;
If state is true that mean video on fullscreen mode. This way can use for detect video fullmode and browser. You can reference in [here](http://www.intheloftstudios.com/blog/detecting-html5-video-fullscreen-and-events)